Git integration breaks with latest update to Overleaf
I am getting the following when I try to git pull from my overleaf git repo:
fatal: unable to access 'https://git.overleaf.com/64bfdcf4c1842d00b03c460a/': The requested URL returned error: 403```



I figured out that you can fix this by getting a token from Overleaf here https://www.overleaf.com/user/settings and telling git to use 'git@' in the URL, e.g.:
git remote set-url origin "https://git@git.overleaf.com/66cc6faf853800aa691f160a"

